# SOAP Xml issue in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, soap, sdk

Methods which take no parameter give correct result as expected. Whereas methods of webservice requiring few parameter returns no relevant result instead show ***Message***.

Im using following code:

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"param1=%@&param2=%@&param3=%@&param4=%@&pageSize=%@&pageNo=%@",@"",@"81",@"1",@"",@"40",@"1"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.someurlxyz.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

soapMsg = [soapMsg stringByAppendingString:post];

NSLog(@"value of soap is %@",soapMsg);
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];
//postData =[postData stringByAppendingString:];

[req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req addValue:@"http://www.someurlxyz.com/Search/Methodname?"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody: [soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[post release];
```

***Message*** (which is getting returned is following).
Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://www.someurlxyz.com/Search/Methodname?

Comment: Please don't express urgency in the title of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a problem with the namespaces or you might be calling a wrong method. 
Use some third party client like SoapUI to check your webservice, and check whether you creating exact string in your request in iPhone app.

Answer (score 0):

What is the server expecting here?

It looks like you are sending `param1=&param2=81&param3=1&param4=&pageSize=40&pageNo=1`

Which doesn't look like an actual soap message or even XML.

You don't specify what `soapMsg` is originally but you're appending the string above to it.

Maybe you intended to format the original `soapMgs` string?

Comment: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
 "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
 "<soap:Body>"
    "<param1 xmlns=\"http://www.mywebsite.com/Method\">"
 "<param2>int</param2>"
   " </param1>"
 "</soap:Body>"
 "</soap:Envelope>"

Comment: i first hit the url it give me the file in xml structure and then i use the xml parser to parse that xml in webDidLoadFinishing

Comment: I'd guess that you should be populating the xml structure and not appending to the end of it. Doing SOAP by formatting strings and appending text is going to be painful. :(

Comment: no these are the parameter are passed in post in POST method in post string ...:). when i hit the web service methods that take no arguemts it fetch data fine i previously parse data in json but for this app data is in xml structure thats why don't know much about xml parsing in iphone

Comment: Good to hear. Care to share how you fixed it or was it a facepalm moment? :)